# How to delete category in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

logged in users can delete categories on posts, but I have an error if I delete the id in the category then when I enter the post dashboard it will get an error because the category name is gone.which is deleted only in the category table but in the post table, posts that have that category are not deleted. here my code :

CategoryController.php

```
public function destroy(Category $category)
    {
        Category::destroy($category->id);
        return redirect('/dashboard/categories')->with('success', 'Category has been delete!);
    }
```

Category.php

```
protected $guarded = ['id'];
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

Post.php

```
protected $guarded = ['id'];
    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
```

index.blade.php

```
 <form action="/dashboard/categories/{{ $category->id}}" method="POST" class="d-inline">
        @method('delete')
        @csrf
        <button class="badge bg-danger border-0" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure wants to delete?')"><span data-feather="x-circle"></span></button>
      </form>
```

i need your opinion about this

Comment: Do you want to delete all of the posts in that category, or recategorize them?

Comment: i want to delete all post owned by the user who is currently logged in in category

Comment: How do I delete all posts that have that category?. @aynber

Comment: You can use [Eloquent events](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#events) to trigger a delete of child posts when the category is deleted.

Comment: how do i do that?... i already have auth() what variable to take? @aynber